# How to add the content of a textarea to the body of an email

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

Hi there: I've created a form in html with a table using select to choose between options. One option is "Other" which generates a new text area input field. Once the form has been completed the user can email it to themselves. I can get this to work for all the select options except the new 'Other" category. Instead of adding the new text to the email body it states "[object HTMLTableCellElement]". I have been trying to get this to work but have been unable to solve it or find an answer that helps me - as a relative newbie to coding I can't help thinking I'm missing something obvious...any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

`

## Email new input

```
    <form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td><select name="variableList" id="variableList" class="select">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose...</option>    
                <option value="Var 1">Var 1</option>
                <option value="Var 2">Var 2</option>
                <option value="Var 3">Var 3</option>
                <option value="Other">Other...</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="newVariable"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="email" name="email" id="emailID" placeholder="Your email address..."></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" class="buttons" onclick="sendEmail()" id="sendEmail()">Email</button></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>`
```

And this is the javascript:

```
        document.getElementById("variableList").addEventListener("change", generateTxtBox);

        var x = 1;

        function generateTxtBox(){
                //Create new input textarea if "Other" is selceted from list of options
                if (x==1 && document.getElementById('variableList').value == "Other") {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute('type', 'textarea');
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your new variable...');
                var parent = document.getElementById("newVariable");
                parent.appendChild(input);
                x += 1;
                }
        }

        function sendEmail(){
            var email = document.getElementById("emailID").value;
            var subject = "Email variables";
            var variableList = document.getElementById("variableList").value;
            document.getElementById("newVariable").addEventListener("change", getText);
                function getText(){
                    document.getElementById("newVariable").textContent = newVariable;
                }
            if (document.getElementById('variableList').value == "Other"){
                window.location = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + newVariable;
            } else {
            window.location = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + variableList;
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments work like this: `variable = [new value];`

Next, you're adding an event listener right before "sending" the email, meaning the function you're setting as handler is never run. Even if it did run, the order is wrong.

Finally, `newVariable` is actually the `id` of the `<td>` you have, which means you're adding a textual representation of the table cell as `body` to the email link.

```js
document.getElementById("variableList").addEventListener("change", txtBox);

function txtBox() {
  // show textarea if "Other" is selected from list of options
  document.getElementById("txtBoxRow").style.display = this.value == "Other" ? "table-row" : "none";
}

function sendEmail() {
  var email = document.getElementById("emailID").value;
  var subject = "Email variables";
  var variableList = document.getElementById("variableList").value;
  var body = variableList == "Other" ? document.getElementById("newVariable").value : variableList;
  window.location = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
}
```

```css
#txtBoxRow {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="variableList" class="select">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose...</option>
          <option>Var 1</option>
          <option>Var 2</option>
          <option>Var 3</option>
          <option value="Other">Other...</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="txtBoxRow">
      <td>
        <textarea id="newVariable"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="emailID" placeholder="Your email address...">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="buttons" onclick="sendEmail()">Email</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was figuring out too, but I was too slow. This should be the answer...

Comment: Thanks so much Chris G for taking the time to explain, I'm really grateful to you - this worked really nicely and I've managed to incorporate it into the site I'm working on; sadly I've still got a way to go to get the hang of this...